References for Intersection Forms
I am currently learning the background materials towards a project on Seiberg-Witten invariants and 4-manifolds. Currently, I am trying to understand the ideas of intersection forms on 4-manifolds and Donaldson's theorem.
Does anyone know of detailed and concise resource(s) on intersection forms? Hopefully one that shows how intersection forms can be defined in different ways, i.e. on de Rham cohomology via integrating differential forms, or via integer cohomology via cup product.
Thanks in advanced.

I recommend the beginning of Scorpan's The wild world of 4-manifolds to get a general feel of the subject before reading drier sources.

See also Pedro's answer  here relating two different descriptions of the intersection form.

4-manifolds and Kirby Calculus is a really good text - I use it a lot currently.
